# How to use dateadd function in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to add character type in SQL Server using `DATEADD` function.

I want the 25th of the next month of the variable.

Example

```
DECLARE @Date char(6)
SET @Date = '201712'
```

I want result = 20180125

```
DECLARE @Date char(6)
SET @Date = '201801'
```

I want result = 20180225

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
dateadd(month, 1, dateadd(day, 25, cast(@date + '01' as date)))
```

You can shorten this to:

```
dateadd(month, 1, cast(@date + '25' as date))
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the month end date by adding '01' to the yyyymm string using `EOMONTH` function and add 25 days to it.

```
select dateadd(day,25,eomonth(@date+'01'))
```